# Is a tree a subtree of another?

Tags: algorithm

From [Lakmann](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/098478280X): Find whether a tree is a subtree of another:
The author says the solution (reproduced below) is O(log(n) + log(m)) memory where n and m are the respective numbers of nodes of each tree. I can't figure out why this is the case. Any pointers?

```java
boolean containsTree(TreeNode t1, TreeNode t2){
    if (t2 == null){
        return true;
    }
    return subTree(t1, t2);
}

boolean subTree(TreeNode r1, TreeNode r2){
    if (r1 == null){
        return false;
    }
    if (r1.data == r2.data){
        if (matchTree(r1, r2)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return (subTree(r1.left, r2) || subTree(r1.right, r2));
}

boolean matchTree(TreeNode r1, TreeNode r2){
    if (r2 == null && r1 == null){
        return true;
    }
    if (r1 == null || r2 == null){
        return false;
    }

    if (r1.data != r2.data){
        return false;
    }

    return (matchTree(r1.left, r2.left) && matchTree(r1.right, r2.right)); 
}
```

Comment: how comes... my intuition is O(m+n).

Comment: is that code coded by you or provided by the book?

Comment: provided by the book and the memory complexity as well

Comment: my bet is O(mn) in the worst case of your code. let me show an example.

Comment: Worst case or average case? I'm pretty sure, worst case of the subtree problem in the general case was somewhere around *O(n²)*. But under the assumption that tree roots are unique, you could arrive at O(log(n)) ...

Comment: The amount of state you have to keep track of is only the depth of the 2 trees. If the trees are balanced it is O(log(n) + log(m)).

Comment: @Phylogenesis it's not necessary balanced.

Comment: I forgot to say it is binary trees

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr I added that as a proviso.

Comment: @Phylogenesis even if it's balanced, the key is not necessary to be sorted. in the provided code, there is no comparison made. if it's balanced but not sorted, the complexity will be `O(2^(log(n)-log(m))*m)=O(n)`.

Comment: Why would anyone make an unsorted tree? That defeats the whole point of having a binary tree in the first place.

Comment: @Phylogenesis: There are many applications of trees which have nothing to do with sorting. For example, it is common to represent parsed expressions as trees (label is operator, children are operands), and the subtree query is similar to a search for common subexpressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please consider this specific example:

t1

```
            1
           /
          1
         /
        1
       /
      1
     /
    1
   /
  1
```

t2

```
    1
   / \
  1   1
```

now check if t2 is contained in t1.

no doubt, `matchTree` will fail in the last step, and t1 will walk through the whole tree to find out it's not contained.

therefore, in degenerated trees, it would be the worst case, and the complexity will be O(mn).

## UPDATE:

if the two trees are balanced, but not sorted, the only thing can be optimized, is that we know we can stop when the subtrees of t1 is shorter than t2, that is `log(n) < log(m)`, so the complexity can be optimized to

```
O(2^(log(n)-log(m))*m) = O(n/m*m) = O(n)
```

## UPDATE2:

if it's sorted, and no duplicated elements, then the root of t2 can be found in t1 in `O(log(n))`(if exists), and a tree traversal needs to be performed, which is `O(m)`. so it should sum up to be `O(log(n) + m)`.

Comment: If you're going to talk about an unsorted tree, you might as well talk about a hash table with a single bucket. The asymptotic complexity of every operation breaks in a tree if it's unsorted.

Comment: @Phylogenesis it really doesn't matter in given implementation. it will walk the whole tree in the worst case any way. as i said, there is no comparison made in the code.

Comment: Also, the question asks about memory usage, not algorithmic complexity, and that's bounded by the height of the 2 trees.